# How to test the a protected inherited method from superclass in another package

Tags: java

I have the abstract class and subclass:

A.java:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class A {

    protected abstract int getInt();

    protected List<Integer> get10Int() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            list.add(getInt());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

AImp.java:

```
package myOtherPackage;

import myPackage.A;

public class AImp extends A {
    @Override
    protected int getInt(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I define a test in the same package as the subclass:

```
package myOtherPackage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class AimpTest {
    @Test
    public void testProtectedMethodFromSuperClass(){
        AImp aimp = new AImp();
        assertEquals(aimp.get10Int().size(), 10);
    }
}
```

and I get an error because `get10Int()` has protected access in `myPackage.A`. Is there any way I can test this method (which is an inherited method of a superclass in another package) while keeping `AImp` and `AImpTest` in `myOtherPackage`, and also keeping the superclass in its own package?

Comment: You don't. Test the **observable, external behaviour** of your classes. These classes have none.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally create a test for class A, in your test use a dummy implementation and then test out your function. This way the test is not required on every implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer in that you should write a Test for the class `A` in it's package, because what you are testing is functionality of `A` and not `AImp`, but if you really want to access protected (or even private) methods you can do it like this:

```
@Test
    public void testProtectedMethodFromSuperClass(){
        AImp aimp = new AImp();

        Method get10IntMethod = AImp.class.getDeclaredMethod("get10Int");
        get10IntMethod.setAccessible(true);

        List<Integer> result = (List<Integer>) get10IntMethod.invoke(aimp);

        assertEquals(result.size(), 10);
    }
```

And if you want to call a method with arguments (e.g. `otherMethod(int)`) you have to pass the argument types to `getDeclaredMethod()` like this: `getDeclaredMethod("otherMethod", int.class)`
and the arguments to invoke: `method.invoke(instance, 5)`.